# cs 61b project1b Cannot resolve method get in Deque

Tags: java

I wrote these codes in Idea. The IDE throws "can't resolve method get in Deque.java" when I finished Palindrome.java. How come? I actually did that in the Deque.java. Although in the LinkedListDeque inherited the get() method from the origin LinkList.

I found another solution by changing

```java
Deque stringDeque =  wordToDeque(word);
```

to

```java
LinkListDeque stringDeque = (LinkListDeque) wordToDeque(word);
```

But I am still curious about how cannot find get in Deque.

[class diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtDkp.png)
Deque interface

```java
/** Create an interface in a new file named Deque.
 * java that contains all of the methods that appear in both ArrayDeque and LinkedListDeque.
 * @param <Item>
 */

public interface Deque<Item> {

    int size = 0;
    /** Adds an item of type T to the front of the deque. */
    void addFirst(Item item);

    /** Adds an item of type T to the back of the deque. */
    void addLast(Item item);

    /** Returns true if deque is empty, false otherwise. */
    default boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    };

    /** Prints the items in the deque from first to last,
     * separated by a space. Once all the items have been printed, print out a new line. */
    void printDeque();

    /** Removes and returns the item at the front of the deque. If no such item exists, returns null. */
    Item removeFirst();

    /** Removes and returns the item at the back of the deque. If no such item exists, returns null. */
    Item removeLast();

    /** Gets the item at the given index, where 0 is the front, 1 is the next item, and so forth.
     * If no such item exists, returns null. Must not alter the deque! */
    Item get(int index);
}
```

class LinkedLinkDeque.java

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * Isn't this solution kinda... cheating? Yes.
 */
public class LinkedListDeque<Item> extends LinkedList<Item> implements Deque<Item> {

    @Override
    public void printDeque() {
        System.out.println("dummy");
    }

    public Item getRecursive(int i) {
        return get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Item removeFirst() {
        try {
            return super.removeFirst();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Item removeLast() {
        try {
            return super.removeLast();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Palindrome.java

```java
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Palindrome {

    /** Given a String, wordToDeque should return a Deque
     * where the characters appear in the same order as in the String.
     * @param word
     */
    public Deque<Character> wordToDeque(String word) {
        Deque<Character> stringDeque = new LinkedListDeque<>();
        for (String s : word.split("")) {
            stringDeque.addLast(s.charAt(0));
        }
        return stringDeque;
    }

    /** Return true if the given word is a palindrome, and false otherwise. */
    public boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        if (word.length() == 0 || word.length() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        Deque stringDeque =  wordToDeque(word);
        int index = word.length() / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i += 1) {
            if (stringDeque.get(i) != stringDeque.get(word.length() - i - 1)) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your own `Deque` interface but you are also working with the `java.util.Deque` interface. This can result in problems as the interface `Deque` is defined twice in different namespaces. Specially in your `Palindrome.java` file you are using the `java.util.Deque` interface because of the `import java.util.Deque` line at the top and **NOT** your `Deque` interface as you might expect.

Because of that you get the error message that the `get(int)` method is missing. That is correct, the [`java.util.Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) method does not define a `get(int)` method (but the [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) interface does).

Do not name classes with names which already exists in java. As you see that can result in naming conflict/issues.